# Laravel Mail works for one but not there other

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-5.1

For this website I have a contact form, which simply sends a mail like this:

```
Mail::send('emails.contact', $input, function ($m) {
    $m->from(Input::get('email'), Input::get('name'));
    $m->to('secretaris@****.nl', 'Secretaris ****')->subject('Contactform: '. Input::get('name'));
});
```

The $input variable is simply:

```
$input = Input::all();
```

Then the view looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<b>{{$name}} ({{$mail}}) sent u a message via the contactform on ****.nl</b>
<br>
<div>
{{$message}}
</div>
<br>

</body>
</html>
```

This mail **does** send. But this one somehow doesn't:

```
Mail::send('emails.registermember', $data, function ($m) {
    $m->from('no-reply@****.nl', 'No-Reply ****');
    $m->to('secretaris@****.nl', 'Secretaris ****')->subject('Registration of ' . ucfirst(Input::get('firstname')) . ' as Register-member');
});
```

The $data value here is:

```
$data = [
    'naam' => ucfirst($user->voornaam) . ' ' . ucfirst($user->achternaam),
    'id' => $user->id,
];
```

With the view:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>
    <b>{{$name}}</b> registered as register member at website of ****.
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

This mail does not send and doing Mail::failures() returns:

```
[
"secretaris@****.nl",
]
```

I don't see what's the difference between those mail functions, and why one works and the other doesn't.

For privacy reasons I marked the website name with ****

I hope someone can help me out!

Thanks

Comment: What mail driver are you using?

Comment: The data you are sending is `naam`, but in the view, you put `$name`.

Comment: That's right, I translated it but forgot to translate it there. It's the same in my code (naam and $naam)

Comment: I am using the providers SMTP server. It's not the mail driver though (I think) because the contact form does send the mail but the registration doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I suspect the error is in this line

`$m->from('no-reply@****.nl', 'No-Reply ****');`

- Please check if you can sent out an email via this email through Laravel

`no-reply@****.nl`

- Check to see if you configure it properly in `.env` file

Comment: That solved my problem! Does the e-mailadres you're trying to send from need to exist? Because no-reply didn't exist on the server. Anyways I used info@****.nl which worked perfectly fine.