# Laravel Mail, "from" always need to be the same as "username"?

Tags: php, laravel, email

If I'm firing an e-mail from `mysite@mysite.com.br` but if I change the from to another e-mail like `company@company.com.br` it falls into `Mail::failures()`

**It DOESN'T Works**

```
// username = 'mysite@mysite.com.br' 
// password = 'mypassword'   

Mail::send("mail.test", [], function ($message) {
    $message->to('client@client.com')
          ->from('company@company.com' , 'Company');
});
```

`client@client.com` falls into `Mail::failures()`

---

**It Works**

but if I change it to:

```
// username = 'mysite@mysite.com.br' 
// password = 'mypassword'   

Mail::send("mail.test", [], function ($message) {
    $message->to('client@client.com')
          ->from('mysite@mysite.com.br' , 'My Site');
});
```

Comment: Sounds like your mail server doesn't want to forward mail for strangers. This isn't a programming issue; it's an administrative one. (Might be fixed by a SPF record, depending on the smtpd configuration. If you don't know what that means, talk to your systems admin.)

Comment: @cHao I know how to update the TXT DNS for SPF, but witch domain needs to authorize? the one I'm firing from? or the one I'm putting in "from" method? I mean, in my example, client.com or mysite.com.br?

Comment: If it's the problem, then the record on client.com would need to list your mail server.

Comment: @cHao okay but why can't I fire an e-mail from "sender@mysite.com.br" with the `from` "user@mysite.com.br"? It also falls into Mail::failures()

Comment: My server is configured with the following SPF `v=spf1 include:_spf.admincontrolpanel.com a mx ~all`

Comment: Your mail server might only want to see a `from` that matches up with your username. Sounds boneheaded to me, but i've seen worse. As for the SPF record, it needs to be on the domain you're sending mail on behalf of. (And BTW...the record at `_spf.admincontrolpanel.com` basically ignores everything after it. Put the `include:` at the end of the record, right before the `~all`, if you want anything else to be honored. But unless it's on the same domain you're putting in `from`, it won't help anyway)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Mail works for one but not there other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34634216/laravel-mail-works-for-one-but-not-there-other)

Comment: @cHao this question you marked as duplicated didn't solve my problem :( I changed the order in my SPF `v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.admincontrolpanel.com` but still can't send e-mails from my own domain, What do I need to confg to allow it?

Comment: Check your mail server before you worry too much more about your code. (If you have shell access, try sending a couple of test emails from the machine using the `mail` command. That'll help clear up whether it's you or your mail server that's at fault.) Talk to the people who run the mail server; they'll be able to tell you what you need to get them to accept your mail. It might be as simple as asking them to add an alias or something.

Comment: Yea I talked with the server support and he said it is blocked, thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my mail server, I talked with the support from my server and he said It its block for fraude reasons